# How to filter JUNIT Tests that are called from eclipse by source path

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Assuming that I have a set of source folders in an Eclips project:

```
MyProject
  base/src/impl
  base/src/test
  common/src/api
  common/src/test
  common/src/junit
```

Note that these are not packages, they are source folders, inside each one there's a package hierarchy, which can be just the same. Let's say if I have a class com.foo.myproject.DoSomething in the base/src/impl folder, I might have a Test called com.foo.myproject.DoSomethingTest in the base/src/Test folder, and maybe com.foo.myproject.DoSomethingUnitTest in another source folder under same package hierarchy.

What I need to do, is run all tests that are under certain source folders. Maybe all that are in a junit folder, but none from the test folder.

This works fine from Ant with the junit search patterns, for example:

```
<include name="**/src/junit" />
```

However, I want to be able to have exactly the same run configurations from Eclipse without having to call Ant. Since there are already many projects, packages and thousands of Test Classes, I am looking for a "lazy" way to get this done, that means, without having to change project structures or having to mantain complex test suites.

One Approach I have tried is to use the `org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` used by ClasspathSuite, but looking for resources in classpath always looks at the merged source folders in one single classes location, so I am not able to filter anymore at the level I intend to do it.

I am looking for two ways of doing it:

```
1. Filter using some TestSuite
2. Filter using some JUNIT Runner Plugin in Eclipse (is there any that can do what I need?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using maven? Take a look at: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html.

Comment: Nope, but the issue is not about the building system. This project uses Ant and it does it well (from command line), maven also does it well from command line (have used it before). But the issue is trying to match a Test execution (ant or maven) from eclipse without having to dig into what you want to call. I would like to have a TestSuite or Run configuration that can do exactly what ant or maven do, but running natively from eclipse (seeing unit test results in the eclipse junit view, not in the console). However these should search for the classes just like Ant or maven do.

Answer (score 5):

You can right-click the source folder, and select Run As> JUnit Test.

This will run the unit tests in this source folder only.

---

Alternatively, when editing the Run Configuration, you can select

[image: Run Configuration]

`Run all tests in the selected project, package or source folder:`

Press `search` and select the folder you wish to run the unit tests of.

See "Customizing a Test Configuration" on [Writing and Running JUnit tests](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm) of the Eclipse Help.

---

[Same page](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-junit.htm) describes how to create a custom Test Suite using the New Test Suite wizard.

[image: New Test Suite wizard]

Comment: Hi Flup, the approach tocreate a Test Suite is not an option as it would make Developers mantain that Suite, and since we have many projects, it would be a sure failure... The first approach is partially OK. If I once create all the run configurations for the proper source folders, I can use some tool like "Eclipse Runner" and group the run configurations as I need them. This seems the best approach until now, but I was really looking for something more "automated" that could use some input like the ant batch runs or the maven test runs, but from Eclipse...

Comment: My favorite would be the very first option, simply right-click the folder and run its unit tests.

Comment: Yep, but the project has like 8 source folders with Unit Tests. I want the developer to be able to runn them all, but without running the other 7 that are Integration Tests... I know it's not a nice scenario, that's why I'm looking for ways to improve the situation...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project that seems to make what you want:

[ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp)

Look for "Classpath Property Annotation" in order to set a folder from where the tests are taken.

Besides, if your test classes are really named as they seam to (all Unit Tests classes have the suffix UnitTest), then you could also use the `@ClassnameFilters` annotation.

Comment: Well, I tried that approach, but it really doesn't do what I need as it will lookup in the build folder from Eclipse where all classes are merged. If two source folders have tests with the same package, ClasspathSuite is not able to find them...

Comment: Just to complement, the approach I mentioned with PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver is just the Package that ClasspathSuite uses internally... I will update the post to mention that ClassPathSuite uses it. I analyzed the code to see what it really does internally...

Comment: See my updated answer, with the `ClassnameFilters` annotation.

Comment: OK, thank you. The issue is that all tests end with "Test" (even those that are not pure unit tests), so I would have to rename all UnitTests from "*Test" to "*UnitTest". This might really solve the issue, but it's almost the same effort as trying to migrate all Tests to JUNIT4.x notation and add a Category and use a CategoryFilter... I will still consider it as an option if for some reason migrating the tests results too risky to be done on a "batch" task...

Comment: By the way, I see that I mixed the ClasspathSuite with the ResourcePatternResolver. Both work similarly, but I don't know wether ClasspathSuite uses the Resolver internally. Both deliver similar results, being the main issue that they lookup on target (merged) folder. I am trying to lookup by source folder in eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but for posterity - JUnit 5 now has tags which you can use to do this (see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering). You can tag all your integration tests with a particular tag and then in your test launch configuration you can exclude tests with that tag (or vice-versa - tag all your pure unit tests and include only those).

This is similar in operation to JUnit 4 Categories which I can see in one of your comments you already considered and rejected as being too much effort to migrate to manually and too risky to migrate to automatically. So in your situation it might not be the solution of choice. Do note that tags can be added at the test class level and not just at the method level, so in your case that might make migration easier. But regardless if this is not the best solution for your project with a lot of history and inertia, I think it would be the ideal approach for a "greenfield" project, so I still thought it worthwhile to add it as a solution here in case it is useful for someone else.